# WP plugin for gallery shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I need some plugin with shortcodes, where i can chose type of gallery/slideshow and put url of images.

I.e. in my post i will do somthing like

```
[some_plugin_name galery_type="some-value" img="www.example.com/01.jpg,www.example.com/02.jpg,www.example.com/03.jpg"  ]
```

Point is putting url of images into shorcode, do you know some plugin what I need?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but if i could than i would do it... but i really need it as i wrote

Comment: I think, You need to create custom plugin for that.